# How to write validations for email and password using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks

I am working on React in that project I am trying to write validations for Email and password by
using react hooks But I don't know how to start it write it so please help to achieve this.
What I want exactly is I hard coded Email and Password in my code. Now Just I want to write validations for Email and Password. What I want exactly is If I enter Incorrect Email and Correct password  then in Validations it have to show only please enter valid email address.
If I enter correct Email then it has to show please enter correct password. If both are wrong means then it has to show validations please enter correct Email and Password.

This is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

const Login = () => {

    const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState(null)

    const loginCredentials = () => {
        if (loginData.email === 'john@gmail.com' && loginData.password === 'christina') {
        } else {
        }
    }


    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target
        const newData = Object.assign({}, loginData, { [name]: value })
        setLoginData(newData)
    }


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        loginCredentials()
    }  

return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <div className='mainform mt-3'>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name='email' className="form-control" id="email" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name='password' className="form-control" id="password" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                    
                            <button type="submit"  className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the errors in an array and check the length of array at the end.

```
const [errors,setErrors]=useState([]);
.
.
.
if(username !='john@gmail.com')
{
   setErrors([...errors,{error:'Invalid username'}])
}
if(password!='something')
{
   setErrors([...errors,{error:'Invalid password'}])
}
```

Now inside of the component

```
{errors?errors.map(elem=>elem.error):null}
```

Comment: This way you can structure getting an error inside of ReactJS from the backend as well. So if you choose to have same structure of error then alll you really need to do is  put `{errors?errors.map(elem=>elem.error):null}` at the top component and change the state via a state management and perhaps handle the close events accordingly but this provides with a pretty good start.

Comment: I would strongly discourage going by the `if ...else` path , since you have only 2 fields at the moment , if you have a confirm password field , your loops increase and the chance of leaving out some corner case  might arise at a later point whih would be harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state for the error message and change its value based on what combination of email and password is incorrect. If

```
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')
const loginCredentials = () => {
        if (loginData.email !== 'john@gmail.com' && loginData.password !== 'christina') {
         setErrorMessage('email and pw are both incorrect')
        } else if (loginData.email !== 'john@gmail.com' {
         setErrorMessage('email is incorrect')
        } else if {.....etc
    }
```

then put {errorMessage} in your jsx where you want it to show up

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested if else

```js
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const loginCredentials = () => {
    if (loginData.email === "john@gmail.com") {
        if (loginData.password === "christina") {
            setError("");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            setError("Incorrect Password");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        setError("Incorrect Email and password");
        return false;
    }
};
```

To show the error you can put a div somewhere in the form which will only show when there is error.

`{error && <div>{error}</div>}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your input values are not controlled elements. learn about 'controlled component'.

There are lots of ways you can achieve this.
I think you can add a custom hook to handle onChange and reset handler.

custom hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useInputState = (initialValues) => {
  const [state, setstate] = useState(initialValues);

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => setstate({
    ...state,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  });

  const reset = (field) => {
    if (field) {
      setstate({
        ...state,
        [field]: initialValues[field],
      });
    } else {
      setstate({
        ...initialValues,
      });
    }
  };

  return [state, onChangeHandler, reset];
};

export default useInputState;
```

Then consume that hook in your component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import UseInputState from '../hooks/useInputState';

const App = () => {
  const [value, onChangeHandler, reset] = UseInputState('');

  console.log({ value });

  const [emailAlert, setEmailAlert] = useState(null);
  const [passwordAlert, setPasswordAlert] = useState(null);

  const loginCredentials = () => {
    setEmailAlert(null);
    setPasswordAlert(null);
    const { email, password } = value;
    if (email !== 'john@gmail.com') {
      setEmailAlert('Please Enter valid Email Address');
    }
    if (password !== 'christina') {
      setPasswordAlert(' please enter correct password');
    }

    reset('');

    if (password === 'christina' && email === 'john@gmail.com') {
      setEmailAlert(null);
      setPasswordAlert(null);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginCredentials();
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row justify-content-center'>
        <div className='col-4'>
          <div className='mainform mt-3'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
                <input
                  type='email'
                  name='email'
                  className='form-control'
                  id='email'
                  value={value.email || ''}
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
                <input
                  type='password'
                  name='password'
                  className='form-control'
                  id='password'
                  value={value.password || ''}
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                ></input>
              </div>

              <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>

            {emailAlert && <div>{emailAlert}</div>}
            {passwordAlert && <div>{passwordAlert}</div>}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```